# What test do I use for comparing count data for significant differences between two groups of different sizes?

Tags: chi-squared-test, count-data, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, frequency

I need to compare count totals between two groups that are of unequal sizes. For example see table:

[image: Table]

Total injuries includes back/neck injuries.
I am looking to see if the back/neck injuries are significantly higher in one occupation, given the different injury totals and if possible, factoring in number of injury areas. The n is too low for Chi and Mann Whitney U test from what I understand. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you very much!

Comment: Hi do you mind slightly formatting the table a bit, it is hard to read..  and also explain whether the back/neck is a subset of total injuries..

Comment: Formatted table by removing some unnecessary spaces and putting 4 spaces at the start of each line to get 'code' format mode. // But headers still need explanation, as requested by @StupidWolf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Data.** If, as @StupidWolf suggests, 'Back and Neck' injuries are a
category of injuries, so that the rest of 'Total Injuries'
can be considered as a complementary category, then your data table
looks like this:

```
Inj Type \ Occup     CyO     HTO      TOTAL
-------------------------------------------
Back/Neck              1      34         35
Other                  3     216        219
-------------------------------------------
TOTAL                  4     250        254
```

**Chi-squared test of independence.** Then, supposing that there were 254 randomly chosen injuries
altogether, such a table might potentially be analyzed using
a chi-squared test of independence. We enter the data into a matrix in R, and check totals for validity.

```
DTA = matrix(c(1,34, 3,216), byrow=T, nrow=2); DTA
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1   34
[2,]    3  216
rowSums(DTA); colSums(DTA);  sum(DTA)
[1]  35 219
[1]   4 250
[1] 254
```

However, as you say, a chi-squared test is not valid because
the expected number of counts in one of the four cells is far
below 5, required for the chi-squared statistic to have
approximately an chi-squared distribution.

**Fisher Exact Test.** By contrast, [Fisher's Exact Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%27s_exact_test) (as implemented in R) is valid. However, it does
not find significance of association between Occupation and
Injury Type variables.

```
fisher.test(DTA)

        Fisher's Exact Test for Count Data

data:  DTA
p-value = 0.4495
alternative hypothesis: true odds ratio is not equal to 1
```

*Notes:* (1) If the 1:3 ratio of Back/Neck injuries to
Other injuries were to hold up with a larger number of subjects
in the CyO occupational category, then you'd find significance. Consider
the fake data table below. P-values are shown below for both Fisher and chi-square tests:

```
DTA.2 = matrix(c(15,34, 45,216), byrow=T, nrow=2); DTA.2
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   15   34
[2,]   45  216
fisher.test(DTA.2)$p.val
[1] 0.04669228
chisq.test(DTA.2)$p.val
[1] 0.04807218
```

(2) You have enough data for HTO to make a reasonable 95% confidence interval for the proportion of HTO total injuries that are back/neck injuries. The point estimate is $\hat p = 34/250 = 0.126$ one of several kinds of 95% confidence
intervals for $p$ is the 
[Jeffries Interval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval#Jeffreys_interval) $(0.098, 0.183),$ based on a Bayesian method. But for CyO you don't have enough data to make a useful interval estimate.

```
qbeta(c(.025,.975), 34.5, 216.5)
[1] 0.09777243 0.18259443
```

Comment: Thank you! This is great!